# Problems with tolerance in the linkedin application

Tags: linkedin-api

Good time, I had a problem in the process of working the application https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps,
namely, when I got to the POST method https://api.linkedin.com/v2/contactExporterTasks, I get the error {"serviceErrorCode": 100, "message": "Not enough permissions to access: POST / contactExporterTasks," status ": 403}
I have already received access_token information, what permission do I need to get to fix this error?
In the process of solving this error, I found on the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/contacts-api the entry "The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their agreements. ”
What conditions do I need to fulfill in order to become an approved LinkedIn developer?